# Where is the location to check the cause of the goquorum going down?

Tags: go-ethereum, quorum

I am running goquorum image in docker.

But for some unknown reason, the goquorum  goes down.

It is possible to check with docker logs, but since the exact cause is unknown, I want to increase the log level and check the setting and location.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me where it is.

If you know of any other way to determine the cause, please let me know.